# An error occurred while starting the application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I developed a web api with cosmos db .
[full code link](https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi.git)

i got the following error.
[image]

please help me to find what am i doing wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error , it looks like your cosmosdb account uri is wrong. Make sure to have a meaningful url, rather than having it with an id,

Something like,

```
https://psdemo-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/
```

instead of something with decimals.(as it hard to parse)

And do not push your secret keys to your repo.

i see the problem is in the [line](https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi/blob/master/CalalogAPI/DocumentDBRepository.cs#L82)

```
 Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, collectionId, id));
```

you need to pass the partitionKey while you query the data.

Comment: can you try connecting to cosmosdb from the storage explorer whether you are able to connect

Comment: sorry i did not get you . where should i have to do this

Comment: CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(BookCollectionId).Wait();

Answer (score 1):

1- make sure you have the right end-point and key

2- In cosmosDB account blade -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> make sure you are allowing the ip of server that hosts your app to access the cosmos account, In case you have your web app in azure ,check the options [Accept connections from within public azure datacenters]

Just a side note regarding this code in your DocumentDbRepository 
for a better code just use

```
client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
```

instead of using the one you are using in 
https://github.com/kajasumanie/calalogapi/blob/master/CalalogAPI/DocumentDBRepository.cs Line 33
This code need some refactoring